# Applying osm2pgsql .diff patch in windows 7

Tags: osm2pgsql, windows-7

When attempting to run osm2pgsql in command prompt, I ran into the password prompt as described [here](https://trac.openstreetmap.org/ticket/2359). This requires installing a patch. I'm unfamiliar on how to install a .diff patch on Windows 7.

Do I need to install GnuWin as shown [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/15980/12180)?

Thanks for all the help!

**EDIT:** This is the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15510428/osm2pgsql-windows-illegal-option-w-error) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same problem recently and you don't need to apply a patch (especially as the patch is now older than the latest release by about 4 years!).  The new binary version simply does not allow the -W switch (at least not in Windows) and you will get the error message:

> illegal option: -- W

However, the -h help documentation is misleading because it implies you canuse the -W option (and in previous versions you needed to). However, the clue is in the documentation for the -U switch.  All you need to do before running osm2pgsql is temporarily set a PGPASS environment variable by typing at the command prompt:

```
set PGPASS=mypassword
```

Then run osm2pgsql as normal, specifying the username with -U but, of course, omitting -W.

Comment: That did the trick! I edited my original post to include a link from a recent Stack Overflow post with the same question and comment. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest not applying such a change, for the reasons given in the patch response that you linked to. A safer alternative might be to hard-code your password into the script, then protect the script.

However if you understand the consequences of making the change, including potential security issues, then you could hand-apply the change against a current version of the osm2pgsql script.

Essentially, its just going to be a matter of finding the old text, and making it look like the text in the [diff](https://trac.openstreetmap.org/attachment/ticket/2359/osm2pgsql.diff). There have almost certainly been some changes in the original - just adapt the patch to fit. Then rebuild osm2pgsql.